# Web client for spring-data-rest CRUD endpoints?

Tags: spring, crud, spring-data-rest

[Spring Data REST](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) creates a [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) web server with a discoverable API, so it seems it should be possible to write a generalized web client application for it.  Is there such an application?

Comment: can you explain more when you say `write a generalized web client`? like what you are trying to do in detail by updating your post?

Comment: I mean that such a client could use the API to discover what all the entities are and what properties they have, then present an interface to do all the CRUD operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for a HAL browser

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-hal

or

something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-spring-data-rest

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-hal

Answer (score 1):

I hope you mean sample client stubs. Actually a web client cannot be generalized beyond the resources it has. That will not be quite meaningful.

You can try below with swagger. Using swagger here would be really convenient (over raml etc) since spring-data-rest generates swagger it self for you.

- Take your swagger spec
- Paste it at [**https://editor.swagger.io/**](https://editor.swagger.io/).
- Go Generate **Client** => **Your favorite programming language**.

[image]

- Then it will generate sample client stubs for you in the language you have selected.

I think this should be the far most generalized point that makes sense.

**-Addition-**

The primary problem spring-data-rest has solved is abstracting out all the common functionalities attached to controller (ex: response/request mapping etc) and making them readily available and configurable, so that the developer no longer needs to re-invent/duplicate them every time when they are coding a new endpoint.

So as you have suggested generating client-stubs is completely out of spring-data-rest scope. Please read the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks!  Sounds like it's possible to have a generalized "swagger browser", but not one for Spring Data REST, because Swagger contains information that is missing from Spring Data REST.  Is that right?  If so, what's the missing information?

Comment: @Doradus Its more than what you see in browser. You can actually generate client stubs, from which you can crate a full client application. I'm not clear about your question about missing information? Please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks Supun,  Yes, I'm talking about client stubs.  Your answer indicates that it is possible with Swagger; I was inferring that it is impossible with Spring Data REST and was wondering why (ie. what's missing from Spring Data REST).

Comment: @Doradus Yes. Building client stubs are not actually spring-data-rest's job. ;)

Comment: Cool.  So what is missing?

Comment: @Doradus pls read my updated answer with -Addition- heading. Hope it helps. :))

Comment: Thanks!  I still don't quite grasp exactly why this can't be done, but your answer is pretty complete.

Comment: @Doradus pls tell me where do you struggle to understand?